# get internal server error 500 while adding external css file

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter and bootstrap 3.Problem is when i try to add the boostrap css file in my project i get the error.The error gets fixed when i remove the link tag from the code below.WHy i am getting this error and how i can fix this ?please help me out

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
      <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='<?php echo base_url("assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>' >


  </head>
<body>

<h1>this is index</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

in my config.php file i added the base url like the following

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/index.php';
```

and removed the index.php from the following

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in htaccess file in root directory i pasted the following code to remove index.php form url

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You do not need to have index.php here `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycodeigniter/';`

Comment: tried with  $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mycodeigniter/ci/index.php' error remains the same

Answer (score 0):

Remove `index.php` from your `$config['base_url']` too as your rewrite rule removes the `index.php` from the url. So there is no point in still including it in the base url. 
I am guessing your problem is because you have not enabled **mod_rewrite**.
Apache module **mod_rewrite** is required for rewrite rules to work.